# Can't spambots decode encoded email addresses?

Tags: javascript, html, web, obfuscation, spam

I implemented an email encoder for my WordPress site, the plugin will convert an address to something like this

```html
%6f%73%6f%72%69%6f%40%68%65%63%2e%63%6f
```

and decode it via a piece of JavaScript code

```html
<span id="eeb-638789-855127"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("eeb-638789-855127").innerHTML = eval(decodeURIComponent("%6f%73%6f%72%69%6f%40%68%65%63%2e%63%6f"))
</script>
```

I was wondering why this is working to prevent spambots from harvesting emails. Can't spambots decode that encoded address to get the original one?

Comment: It's assumed that spambots don't run client-side JS. So they see the encoded email and not the real one.

Comment: @evolutionxbox they would not actually have to execute any JS, looking for “suspicious patterns” of such encoded sequences would be enough. Once `%6f%73%6f%72%69%6f%40%68%65%63%2e%63%6f` has been extracted and URL-decoded to `osorio@hec.co`, all that’s left is to check, does that match the syntax of an email address.

Comment: @CBroe Agreed. This conspicuous cover-up would make it look more suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

They *could*, and some probably do, it is just cheaper to get addresses from elsewhere instead.